# pipenv run pre-commit --all failed with: An unexpected error has occurred: AttributeError: type object 'Hook' has no attribute 'create

Tags: python, git, code-formatting, pipenv, pre-commit.com

in my pre-commit-config.yaml file i'm trying to run black, the python code formatter

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/python/black
    rev: stable
    hooks:
    - id: black
      language_version: python3.6
```

but whenever I tried running black with `pipenv run pre-commit --all` the code will fail with the error message

```
An unexpected error has occurred: AttributeError: type object 'Hook' has no attribute 'create'
Check the log at some_path
```

when I go to `some_path` I couldn't find any logs there. I tried not running the `pipenv run pre-commit --all` to apply black to my code, but the error still appears when I try to `git commit` any new files.  Any ways to solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue, i'm currently trying to understand the issue. Did you have any success since the problem occured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with python 3.6.0 (this exact patch version) and pre-commit between versions 2.0.0 and 2.1.0

This was fixed in 2.1.1: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#211---2020-02-24

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of pre-commit

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue using python 3.6.0, i've moved up to python 3.6.9 and this error is no more.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try upgrading my python but I tried the steps below and it worked for me

```
1. pipenv shell
2. pip install black
3. black name_of_the_directory_you_want_to_format
```